# Open a form if query returns results on DB open

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query that checks for any records that meet a specific set of criteria. I want some VBA or a macro that runs the query on DB startup and then displays a form if the query returns any results. If not nothing should happen.

Comment: You can use [DCount](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dcount-function-HA001228817.aspx) to find out how many rows are returned from your query.  You can use [DoCmd.OpenForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx) to open a form.  You can create a macro named `Autoexec` to make something happen every time the database is opened in an Access session.

Answer (score 2):

Answer with help from HansUp (above), put the following in the Autoexec:

```
If DCount("*", "Query_name") > 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_name", , , , , acDialog
End If
```